# One line weather output from terminal

Tags: macos, command-line

Anyone knows a way to get a one line weather output in the terminal window with specified location?

So far I'm using curl wttr.in/city but I would like a one output like City, Sunny 0'.

I've found something like this (first answer):
https://askubuntu.com/questions/390329/weather-from-terminal

Unfortunately it does not work. I've installed wget command with brew and tried running those three lines from .sh file.

Comment: Are you struggling to pick out the results from a correct download or are you needing help identifying a source to download? Why not edit this to show the exact site you've chosen to run from `curl` or `wget` if you just need help with `awk` or `cut` to strip out the parts you don't want to see.

Comment: This question doesn't seem related to OS X or Apple products in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is `ansiweather` which you can install with `brew`. The result looks like [image: ansiweather result].

If you want to write you own command/function it's not that difficult. If the output from the online location is in json, or something similar. You can use `jq` to parse json, and only print what you need.

```
curl -s http://ip-api.com/json | jq -Cr .
```

Read the manual page of `jq` to learn how to use it.

I tried the API you're using above, that's not gonna help your case. Find some other one that replies in JSON. For example:

```
curl -s 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={CITY,COUNTRY_CODE}&APPID={GET_YOUR_API_KEY}' | jq -C '.name? .weather?.main?'
```

I haven't tested it personally, because you have to make an account to make a call, but you get the idea.

Comment if you get lost.